# React Native Permission rationale not showing

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-permissions

I'm having a trouble with react native permission rationale. It is not showing though I already put it in my code.

```
const rationale = { title: 'Permission', message: 'message' }
const res = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, rationale);
```

What is the problem why it's not showing? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Late reply, but perhaps this will help someone else who lands here in the future:

I struggled with this as well recently, until I dug into the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid?msclkid=4ab2670dc28d11ec88b7e40cb532b490#request) on `PermissionsAndroid`:

> If rationale is provided, this function checks with the OS whether it is necessary to show a dialog explaining why the permission is needed (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#explain) and then shows the system permission dialog.

While not immediately clear from that line alone, following the provided link to Google's Documentation yielded this valuable snippet:

> If the ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() method returns PERMISSION_DENIED, call shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). If this method returns true, show an educational UI to the user. In this UI, describe why the feature, which the user wants to enable, needs a particular permission.

Essentially, you won't see the rationale on the initial request; it will only be presented after the user has expressly denied the permission (either via the system dialog or through settings). Hope it helps!